# Please help with this OperatioN!

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Hello guys im trying to work out the follow operation with no success:

$$\dfrac{2a^2-2b^2}{3a+3b}\dfrac{\left(a^2-ab\right)3}{a^2-2ab+b^2} = 2a$$

why?
thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use classic formulas for second degree polynomials and basic properties of fractions.

$$\frac{2a^2-2b^2}{3a+3b}\overset{(1)}{=} \frac{2(a^2-b^2)}{3(a+b)} \overset{(2)}{=} \frac{2(a-b)(a+b)}{3(a+b)} \overset{(3)}{=} \frac{2(a-b)}{3}$$ 
$$\frac{\left(a^2-ab\right)3}{a^2-2ab+b^2}\overset{(1)}{=} \frac{3a\left(a-b\right)}{a^2-2ab+b^2}\overset{(2)}{=} \frac{3a(a-b)}{(a-b)^2}\overset{(3)}{=}\frac{3a}{(a-b)}$$
so
$$\frac{2a^2-2b^2}{3a+3b}\frac{\left(a^2-ab\right)3}{a^2-2ab+b^2} \overset{(4)}{=} \frac{2(a-b)}{3}\frac{3a}{(a-b)}\overset{(5)}{=} \frac{3(a-b)}{3(a-b)}2a \overset{(3)}{=} 2a$$

(1) [Factoring by grouping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization#Factoring_by_grouping)

(2) [Perfect square trinomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization#Perfect_square_trinomials) / [Difference of two squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization#Sum.2Fdifference_of_two_squares)

(3) [Simplification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction_%28mathematics%29#Equivalent_fractions)

(4) Substitute above equation

(5) [Fraction multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction_%28mathematics%29#Multiplication)

Answer (score 4):

$$\require{cancel}\begin{align}\dfrac{2a^2-2b^2}{3a+3b}\cdot\dfrac{\left(a^2-ab\right)3}{a^2-2ab+b^2}  
& = \dfrac{2(a^2 - b^2)}{3(a+b)}\cdot \frac{3a(a-b)}{(a-b)^2}\\ \\
& =\dfrac{2(a+b)(a-b)}{3(a+b)} \cdot \frac{3a(a - b)}{(a-b)^2}\\ \\ 
&= \frac{2(\cancel{a-b})}{\cancel 3}\cdot \frac{\cancel{3}a}{\cancel{a-b}}\\ \\ 
& = 2a\end{align}$$